# Homerow computing: How to set Control+K => Arrow down?

Tags: macos, keyboard

System: MacOS 12.x

How can I set up the following shortcuts:

- Control + k = ↓
- Control + i = ↑
- Control + j = ←
- Control + l = →

Paid third party software is ok, but should stay belo 10$.

**Goal:** I'd like to move the cursor around without leaving the basic typing position.

**I've tried** Automator, but

- the action becomes too delayed and
- presses like `press control, k, k, k, release control` won't work.

If I'd be on a Linux machine, I'd let Control+k, ... send arrow key keycodes via the keyboard layout file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Install [Karabiner Elements](https://karabiner-elements.pqrs.org).
2. [Import rules](https://ke-complex-modifications.pqrs.org/#ijkl_arrows).
3. Open the **Complex modifications** tab.
4. Click **Add rule**.
5. Enable the rule called **Change Control + i/j/k/l to Arrows**.